# decorating ConfigParser.get() with ast.literate_eval or eval

Tags: python-2.7, eval, decorator, ini

I would like to automatic evaluate/guess the data type of the data that you can get from an ini file through configparser.

Disclaimer: I do know the security concern of such a thing, but, I trust the files, and, anyway, I am interesting in understanding why the following code doesn't work.

```
import configparser
import ast
sample=u"""
[General]
t=300.
[Section]
t=${General:t}
"""
def decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        try:
            return eval(func(*args,**kwargs))
        except Exception as e:
            print 'Warning'
            return func(*args,**kwargs)
    return wrapper    
parser=configparser.ConfigParser(interpolation=configparser.ExtendedInterpolation())
parser.get=decorator(parser.get)
parser.read_string(sample)
parser.get('Section','t')
```

raises:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable
```

Any ideas/suggestion for a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Well, eval would parse the provided literal expression and returns an evaluated result , It by no mean helps you determine the data type unless you plan to do additional operations on the evaluated output.

Having said that , I can say you have an interesting problem out there , the simplest workaround would be to change t=300. to t='300.' , that should solve the exception. Other way would be to move the eval part out of the decorator

**1)**

```
#  USE QUOTES in to be parsed string 
import configparser
import ast
sample = u"""
         [General]
         t='300.0'   # NOTICE QUOTES
         [Section]
         t=${General:t}
        """

def decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

        try:
            return eval(func(*args, **kwargs))
        except Exception as e:
            print 'Warning'
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
parser = configparser.ConfigParser(
          interpolation=configparser.ExtendedInterpolation()
)
parser.get = decorator(parser.get)
parser.read_string(sample)
parser.get('Section', 't')
```

**2)**

```
#  EVAL outside decorator 
import configparser
import ast
sample = u"""
         [General]
         t=300.0     #  NO QUOTES
         [Section]
         t=${General:t}
        """

def decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

        try:
            func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
parser = configparser.ConfigParser(
          interpolation=configparser.ExtendedInterpolation()
)
parser.get = decorator(parser.get)
parser.read_string(sample)
eval(parser.get('Section', 't'))
```

Using the second method is as good as removing the entire decorator part and using the parser.get directly (in short it adds no value).

I am still wondering why an eval inside the decorator throws an exception.